# Number of subsets of a set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have a question that is: 
" How many subsets with more than two elements does a set with $100$ elements have? "
Can you help me understanding it step by step?
Thanks in advance .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** A set of $m$ elements has $\binom{m}{n}=\frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$, $\ n$-element subsets. So in your case you have to perform the summation of the above values for $m=100$ and $2< n\leq 100$.

**Hint 2 (alternative):** The total number of subsets of a $100$-elements set, is $2^{100}$. How many of them are subsets with less than two elements?

Comment: They are three: empty set, 1-elmt set, and 2-elmt set but, how can I get the number of 2-elmt subsets?

Comment: I meant three types of subsets ..

Comment: Read carefully my post above: the number of $2$-element subsets is $\binom{100}{2}$.

Comment: I got it ... thanks ... but, why the order is not important here?

Comment: What do you mean "the order is not important here"?

Comment: As we selected "Combinations 100 choose 2" it means combination not permutation, right?

Comment: Combinations $\binom{m}{n}$ means: the number of $n$-element subsets that can be chosen out of a set of $m$ (distinct) elements. Mere sets and subsets (with no further structure) do not have any kind of order among their elemenrs. In this sense you are right; they are a different thing than permutations.

Comment: So, why in 2^100 the order matters but, it doesn't in 3-elmnt  or more subsets ?

Comment: Got it ...... thanks .... in this Q order doesn't matter ....